# Tooltip placement in amcharts stacked column graph

Tags: javascript, charts, tooltip, amcharts

I am trying to make custom html tooltip in amcharts stacked column graph.

```
series.tooltipHTML = `
  <h2>{name}</h2>
`;
```

However the tooltips on hovering, instead of coming at the position of the column always comes in the middle of the graph for every column. I have tried all the options like toolTipY given in the demos. How to make the tooltip's position correct that is on top or bottom of the respective column slices.
[Codepen with problem](https://codepen.io/chirag2796/pen/jOWdodb)